# Prevent alert() method from firing twice

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events, mousewheel

I'm working on a script that will show a user different page content in a specified div when the user scrolls up or down. Right now I'm testing the functionality with just having 2 different alerts pop up when the user scrolls. The problem is that the `alert()` method is sometimes firing twice and I have no idea why.

```
$(window).on('wheel', function(event){
   if(event.originalEvent.deltaY < 0){
   
      // mouse wheel up
      event.stopImmediatePropagation();
      alert("You scrolled up!");

   }
   else {
      // mouse wheel down
      event.stopImmediatePropagation();
      alert("You scrolled down!");
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the [event.isImmediatePropagationStopped()](https://api.jquery.com/event.stopimmediatepropagation/) method to check whether this method was called for the event.